# Upload files via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html

Using the `readAsBinaryString` method of the `FileReader`, how properly upload images and such via Ajax? I know how to do the uploading; files get uploaded, and text files do display well but images cannot be rendered after such a transfer over the net. Note: the work is for a web service so I do not have access to server-side scripting.

Comment: Are the images on the server? Is the problem uploading the images or rendering the images?

Comment: Mark, the problem is uploading images properly. They get uploaded but does not open after the upload. Though text files are alright.

Comment: You can't upload files via XMLHttpRequest. How exactly are you doing this?  Can you post the code you're using?

Comment: Pointy, I can upload files via XMLHttpRequest. It ain't my own know-how, so you could google for it. As for images, somehow extra bytes get added to the sourse after the upload, so the file cannot be decoded.